# FileMaker: Is there any native way to get the client's computer name?

Tags: filemaker

Is there a FileMaker (11 Advanced) native way to obtain the client's computer name in a script?  The computer name shown in FileMaker server when displaying clients connected to a database would do nicely.

Purpose: I'm looking to have filemaker recall and set window position based on user and computer.  (The same user could have a different window position and size preference for their laptop than for their desktop -- think of byHost user preferences.)

Alternate: I'm aware that a the client computer name could be grabbed using an external script, but would prefer a native way, if available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am still unable to answer the question as asked.  However, for the purpose stated, I just found the command

```
Get ( SystemNICAddress )
```

It will provide a unique identifier for each computer that will change infrequently.  This is all that is required for my purpose and will likely work better than the value I originally requested.

Comment: Note that Get (SystemNICAddress) can change, for example you may have a user on a laptop that connects to a USB ethernet adapter or an Apple Thunderbolt Display (MacBook Air) - the value returned will be a return delimited list of all adapters

Answer (score 4):

This new function was introduced in FileMaker Pro 12.0:

```
Get ( PersistentID )
```

From the FileMaker documentation at http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/func_ref2.32.54.html:

"*Returns a unique, unchanging identifier for the computer on which FileMaker Pro is running or the device on which FileMaker Go is running, in the form of a 32-digit hexadecimal string.*"

If you're using FMP 12+, this would be a better choice than relying on  `Get(SystemNICAddress)`, which can change.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but we've worked with the same thing for other reasons and maybe this will help someone.

Since it doesn't seem that FM natively has this function built-in, even for version 17, I just made a table with the NIC address records created when the file opens (if it doesn't exist already) and then the DNS name was manually added later. Then the DNS name could be referenced after using GET to find the NIC address. Some computers do have multiple NICs so those are broken up into separate records (it's just returned as a list) but the same DNS name is applied to them all. Except in the case of a VPN NIC which sometimes reports at 00:00:00:00:00:00; those are just ignored. Otherwise you may have multiple computers with the same null NIC - and that isn't helpful. We use the DNS name for reporting of our employees sales in relation to their call volume. And trying to remember the NICs of a hundred computers is not as simple as a DNS name to know where the person was sitting at the time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a native way to do it.

`Get ( HostName )`

But you can't use this with a hosted filed, file needs to be opened on the client machine locally.
There can be other advantages to using local FileMaker files that communicate with hosted files
 - Better performance for graphics heavy layouts
 - Providing an offline cache

Another approach is to use a system shell script.

For completeness sake, a non-native approach, there are a few Filemaker plugins that can provide this functionality. www.360works.com/scriptmaster/

Comment: This won't work currently as the file is hosted.  It is a good idea for future solutions, however.  Any advice on keeping the local FileMaker files in sync in an environment where they would change frequently?

Comment: I think GoZync tries to address this, with a transactional approach.   But when using FileMaker Pro as the client I think simply using the built in FileMaker tools should suffice in most applications.

Answer (score 0):

To identify client with FileMaker 11, I simply use:

```
 Get(DesktopPath)
```

Maybe it could help...

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a correction to this admittedly old thread:
The name that appears in the FileMaker Server's Admin Console for a connected client is the name set in the FileMaker Preferences of that client. By default that is the client computer's current macOS user name, but it can also have a manual override set there in FM Preferences. That value (default or override) is what is returned using the native FileMaker function `Get ( UserName )` (as opposed to what gets the user's Account, `Get ( AccountName )`.
However, it sounds like the original poster was actually asking for the client's own "local hostname", which is what you can view (in macOS) in the client computer's System Settings, under Sharing.
To get that from FileMaker, you would need to use something that can call outside of FileMaker: a plugin to call a simple shell script "hostname", or an AppleScript that gets the hostname and then puts the result somewhere FileMaker can read it (maybe in a temp file).